How to restrict datastore table and Filestore access to other collaborators in my Catalyst project?
I am creating a catalyst project where I added a developer as a collaborator in order to create functions/backend code for my application. I want to restrict the Datastore and Filestore view access to that developer in order to protect my customer privacy, how can I restrict that access for that collaborator?

You can customize the Collaborator access to Catalyst components from the Profile and Permissions feature. The collaborator will be created with a profile such as Project Owner, Admin or Super Admin.
You can edit those permissions for the profile which enables you to control Collaborator access to your catalyst project. You can find the official help documentation for the same here.
